# How can I edit my todo items in React using hooks?

Tags: reactjs

Here is my codesandbox showing the app https://codesandbox.io/s/vibrant-ptolemy-i8f74?file=/src/TodoList.js

Right now the code allows me to add, cross out, and delete a todo item, but I want to be able to edit the todos as well.

I'm not too sure how I would go about it?

This is the current todo item code

```
      const Todo = ({ todos, completeTodo, removeTodo }) => {
        return todos.map(todo => (
          <div className='todo-row'>
            <div
              key={todo.id}
              className={todo.isComplete ? 'complete' : ''}
              onClick={() => completeTodo(todo.id)}
            >
              {todo.text}
            </div>
            <FaWindowClose onClick={() => removeTodo(todo.id)} />
          </div>
        ));
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the todo text in an input and bind it to the data model with an onChange using the todo.id

Comment: Yeah, you'd need to bind the text box to the value - so set the input value=to the text of the selected todo.id and have the onChange change the text

Answer (score 0):

https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-browser-25ciw?file=/src/Todo.js

1. add `updateTodo` function in `TodoList.js`
2. add `props.edit` in `TodoForm.js`
3. create `edit` state in `Todo.js` and change to `TodoForm` component if `edit.id` has value

Comment: how would i make the value display whatever I typed in my todo input whenever I try to edit it? Right now it clears the input form when I click edit and I'd like it to display the current value of whatever was typed

Comment: updated my answer with new link: https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-browser-25ciw?file=/src/Todo.js